# Alternative behaviour of && operator

Tags: apache-flex, operators

I've faced such situation. I've used to program in C#, and such code:

```
if (condition1 && condition2){
   //some actions
}
```

was asking both, condition1 and condition2 to be `true` (the case when they both are giving `false` and the end-result is true, could be achieved in other way).

In Flex, same code would perform "some actions" if the both conditions are `false`. I just was wondering if is there any chance to make it break after finding first `false` in a queue, or I have no choice and should write nested `if`'s?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Flex (actually AS3 to be exact), if condition1 is false, condition2 is not checked.

Comment: Outch .. my bad, missed 1 operator in a complex condition. Thank you :)

Comment: In fact, this is true for all ECMAScript dialects (eg, JavaScript, JScript).

Answer (score 4):

ActionScript stops checking whenever it needs to.

---

```
if( false && true ){
}
```

This stops after the first false.

---

```
if( true && false ){
}
```

This stops after the second false.

---

```
if( true || false ){
}
```

This stops after the first true.

---

```
if( false || true ){
}
```

This stops after the second true.

---

Hope this helps...

Comment: *Sigh* I wish I could mark this as second answer .. thanks for your answer, it's all just my inattention :)